# Discord Bot About Command

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm currently coding a discord bot and i wanted a about command for the bot. This is what I coded but its not working. All my current commands are in separate files from the index.js file in a command folder. Any ideas why this one isn't working?

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: 'about',
    description: 'talks about the bot',
    execute(message) {
            const aboutEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#0099ff')
                .setAuthor('Alien Bot: About')
                .setDescription(`Alien Bot, Created By MountainTiger144, Is A Fun Little Bot Used On ${client.guilds.cache.size}Servers With Commands Like <avatar And More! Check Them Out By Doing <help hub.`)
                .setThumbnail('https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/images/q_auto,f_auto/gigs/125937562/original/4efdc79b0e19dabcb3f6e7bef8318f2794250933/create-a-custom-discord-bot.png', 'https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/images/q_auto,f_auto/gigs/125937562/original/4efdc79b0e19dabcb3f6e7bef8318f2794250933/create-a-custom-discord-bot.png')
                .addFields(
                    { name: 'Guilds', value: `${client.guilds.cache.size}`, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Version', value: `${bot_info.version}`, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Rating', value: '7/10', inline: true },
                    { name: 'Support Server', value: 'If you need help or find a bug, please click the link [here](https://discord.gg/n293gkD) to get to our support server!', inline: true })
                
                channel.send(exampleEmbed);
            }
        }
```

This Is what comes up when i do <about:

```
ReferenceError: client is not defined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\kiera\Desktop\Discord Bot\commands\about.js:10:104)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kiera\Desktop\Discord Bot\index.js:79:11)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\kiera\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\kiera\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\kiera\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\kiera\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\kiera\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\kiera\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `client` through your `execute()` function in your main file, if you already pass it there then just add `client` to your `execute()` function in your command files like so:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'about',
    description: 'talks about the bot',
    execute(message, client) {...}
```

Comment: that does not make any difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

`execute()` doesn't know what client is, since it hasn't been passed in, or otherwise defined.  Usually when I run into this problem, just add "message." before the "client", then you're using `message.client.guilds.cache.size` and that should work for you, since message *has* been passed in.

Alternatively you can pass in client from your index.js file as a parameter, then that does basically the same thing, though that may affect your other commands, since they may not use a "client" parameter.